# Rotation 2d top-down view in 3d game

Tags: c#, rotation, quaternion

I have a game in top-down view, with little ants who can walk up/down, left/right and diagonal (and all direction with Joystick).

My little player can move, but I can't rotate it properly...
See what i mean in the youtube video of 7 seconds i made:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mGMPhJ-u4s&feature=youtu.be

See the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
public float lookSpeed = 10;
private Vector3 curLoc;
private Vector3 prevLoc;

void Update()
{
    InputListen();
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.position - prevLoc), Time.fixedDeltaTime * lookSpeed);
}

private void InputListen()
{
    prevLoc = curLoc;
    curLoc = transform.position;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        curLoc.y -= 1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
        curLoc.y += 1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        curLoc.x += 1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        curLoc.x -= 1 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    transform.position = curLoc;

}
```

}

I have tried a LOT of ways, but nothing worked...
I have also an animator with a stylesheet (ants walking):
[image]

[image]

thanks !

EDIT: i try another aproch for moving:

```
transform.Translate(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

and for rotating:

```
transform.up = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
```

It move well.. but it doen't rotate when i move... BUT when i collide with another object, my player get some velocity, and then rotate correctly without touching any input, see in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AS3agqJbVtI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I cannot see the video

Comment: You want your character to be able to rotate and it's not working with the right joystick?

Comment: Edited, i want to move my character, and set the rotation in the direction of movement...

Comment: Check here for some help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/510231/how-to-rotate-the-player-in-direction-of-movement.html

Comment: Double-check your use of [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html). It assumes 3D rotation with the _world up_ as the default upwards. For unity 2D this means the z-axis, in and out of the screen. The rigid body collision causes the proper rotation you're seeing because _local (ie ant)_ x and y rotation are constrained, but rotation around the z-axis (again, the axis pointing in and out of the screen in unity 2D) is free. Your ant's _local_ `transform.up` points along the length of its body, so that's the vector you should be rotating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Made it ! Thanks yo _TOM
First, I draw guizmo to help me visualized the transform.up vector:

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Color color;
    color = (nb_player == 1) ? Color.blue : Color.red;
    // local up
    DrawHelperAtCenter(this.transform.up, color, 2f);
}

private void DrawHelperAtCenter(
                    Vector3 direction, Color color, float scale)
{
    Gizmos.color = color;
    Vector3 destination = transform.position + direction * scale;
    Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, destination);
}
```

Then I made my function of movement, called in Update():

```
void MoveNew()
{
    //I don't want any angular velocity when i don't move !
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    if (nb_player == 1)//I have keyboard input ZQSD for player 1, and arrow key for player 2
    {
        float heading = Mathf.Atan2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //if not, the rotation will go back to 0 when no input happened, note the use of "GetAxisRaw" very important, because returning 0 when not moving
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") != 0)
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -heading * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

        transform.Translate(((this.transform.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * speed) * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(((-this.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) * speed) * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    else if (nb_player == 2)
    {
        float heading = Mathf.Atan2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal2") * speed * Time.deltaTime, Input.GetAxis("Vertical2") * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal2") != 0 || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical2") != 0)
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, -heading * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

        transform.Translate(((this.transform.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical2")) * speed) * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(((-this.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal2")) * speed) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I havn't try it wet With Joystick, but i believe the result is the same...